# Azure DevOps YAML pipeline manual intervention job run in parallel with other job

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I want the jobs to go one after another and the first job should control the execution of the following one.

As there are no approvals currently available in the YAML pipeline for deployment outside Kubernetes, I'm using the Manual Intervention to stop the job from being run. But apparently, it doesn't stop the job before instead, it stops the upcoming stage. What do I do wrong? I would expect some notification on the intervention, but it fails immediately and doesn't stop the next job at all.

[image]

This is the part of the code for the Deploy STG stage, where the `parameters.interventionEnabled` is set to `true`

```
jobs:
- job: RunOnServer
  displayName: 'Reject or resume'
  pool: server
  continueOnError: false
  steps:
  - task: ManualIntervention@8
    displayName: 'Manual Intervention'
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    inputs:
      instructions: 'reject or resume'
    enabled: ${{ parameters.interventionEnabled }}

- job: Deploy
  displayName: ${{ parameters.name }}
  pool:
    name: ${{ parameters.agentPoolName }}
  steps:
  - checkout: none # skip checking out the default repository resource

  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    displayName: Download NPM build artifact
    inputs:
      artifact: ${{ parameters.artifactName }}
      buildType: 'current'
      targetPath: ${{ parameters.artifactPath }}
```

Comment: The [Manual Intervention task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-intervention?view=azure-devops) seems can only work in [UI rather than YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops#configure-a-manual-intervention). The requirement description is just what [this roadmap saying](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/edit/1510336) which is provided by @Eric Smith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now available:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

```
- task: ManualValidation@0
  timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
  inputs:
    notifyUsers: |
      test@test.com
      example@example.com
    instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
    onTimeout: 'resume'
```

Answer (score 5):

Hey Andree `ManualIntervention@8` is not supported in YAML. It is roadmapped for [2020\Q2](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/edit/1663893).

I think the route you want to go down is to use [approvals](https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/edit/1510336) with [generic environment types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#creation).

So you define a [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) and environment in your yaml like so

```
- deployment: DeploymentHosted Context
  displayName: Runs in Hosted Pool
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  # creates an environment if it doesn't exist
  environment: 'Dev'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - bash: |
            echo This multiline script always runs in Bash.
            echo Even on Windows machines!
```

And you use the GUI to protect the Environment.

- Navigate to *Pipelines* -> *Environments*.
- Select the Environment (you can pre-create them).
- Then add and an Approval

  [image: approvals menu]

[image: approvals]

There are some drawbacks when compared to classic release definitions and being able to manual trigger to stages. You may not want every artifact to be a candidate for each stage, and if you don't approve the environment it will eventually timeout and report failure. Other good discussion in the [comments here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass).

Comment: Thank, but the problem is I don't use the environment as this release pipeline doesn't release to AKS but the compiled React SPA applications to the BLOB, so the environments are not applicable in this case. :(

Comment: @Andree you can create an generic environment to represent your React SPA. Environments do not have to be AKS. You create the environment with no resources, and then you can protect it with Approvals following the workflow above.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't realized that and it really resolved my situation.